# Ошибка при переходе на следующее Activity

Tags: java, android

Создаю приложение на Android на Java и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть две Activity - MainActivity и CreateQuizActivity. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку происходил переход с MainActivity на CreateQuizActivity. Но когда я нажимаю приложение вылетает. Снизу код и логи ошибки.

Код MainActivity

```
package com.quizop.quizop2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.quizop.quizop2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }

    public void startQuizFunc(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,CreateQuizActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Код CreateQuizActivity

```
package com.quizop.quizop2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.quizop.quizop2.databinding.ActivityCreateQuizBinding;

public class CreateQuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityCreateQuizBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityCreateQuizBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_create_quiz);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_quiz);
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_create_quiz);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }



}
```

Логи

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            
Process: com.quizop.quizop2, PID: 5169
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quizop.quizop2/com.quizop.quizop2.CreateQuizActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4166)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4312)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2571)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3555)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$Api28Impl.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:881)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:376)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:48)
                                                                                                        at com.quizop.quizop2.CreateQuizActivity.onCreate(CreateQuizActivity.java:31)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8578)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8557)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4147)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2571) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741) 
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Comment: Ну почитай ошибку, все написано

Comment: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
Проблема в xml или java?

Comment: @retr12, возможно вы ID-шники перепутали. Покажите разметку второго активити, укажите какая строка 2 активити - 31-ая и отформатируйте как-то лог ошибки - его крайне не удобно читать, он слишком широкий

Comment: @ЮрийСПб CreateQuizActivity - 2 активити. 31 строка: `NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_create_quiz);`

Comment: А разметка? Там есть что-то с ID `nav_host_fragment_content_create_quiz`?